# rotate using animate in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, css-transitions

Hi Friends I am trying to create a popup box which will be appear after clicking on Login button I want to open popup box with rotate effect but failed to achieve the goal you can **[check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Km5GL/1/)** or you can check my code mentioned below...

**SCRIPT**

```
        $('.login').click(function(){
            $('.loginWrapper').css('display','block');
        /*Trying to do something like this

        $('.loginBox').animate(function(){      
                transform: 'rotateX(-60deg)'
                })

        */
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="login">Login</button>


<div class="loginWrapper">
  <div class="loginBox loginRotate"> <img src="images/Cancel.png" width="32" height="32" alt=" " class="cancel">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name=" " id=" " value="Email ID" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''">
      <input type="password" name=" " id=" " value="Password" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''">
      <div class="forgotPassword"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
      <input name="" type="submit" value="Login">
      <div class="forgotPassword">Don't have an account? <a href="#">Get in touch</a> with our Sales team.</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blksheet {
    background: url(../images/blkSheet.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999;
    display:none;
}
.loginWrapper{
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    perspective: 500px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%; 
    z-index: 99999999;
    display:none;
    }
.loginRotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    transform: rotateX(-60deg);}
.loginBox {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transform-origin:50% 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.loginBox .cancel {
    position: absolute;
    right: -18px;
    top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.loginBox h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #ED1C24;
}
.loginBox input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #666;
}
.loginBox input[type="submit"] {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    border: #95191d solid 1px;
    background: #e31c23; /* Old browsers */
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 0px rgba(109, 9, 12, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    font-family: 'Bariolbold';
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.loginBox input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #b4030a; /* Old browsers */
}
.loginBox .forgotPassword {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.loginBox a {
    color: #0088CC;
}
.loginBox input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.loginBox input, select, textarea, input[type="password"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: medium none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use css-transitions for that and change transform-rotate property:

**JS**

```
$('.loginRotate').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'
});
```

**CSS**

```
.loginRotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease -webkit-transform;
    transition: 0.5s ease transform;
}
```

---

Best way - add separate class for this parameters

**JS**

```
$('.loginRotate').addClass('spot');
```

**CSS**

```
.loginRotate.spot {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg),
    transform: rotate(0deg)
}
```

---

**Updated fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Km5GL/2/

Comment: Thanks for help now working .. but popup effect is not same in both browsers mozilaa and chrome

Comment: I think, problem in origins. Play with transform-origin or perspective-origin css3-properties, that's should be similar, not default for current browser

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might be usefule for your need.

http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/